# SQL Server performance Issue. When ever the number of record "In parameter" increases, Query performance is degraded significantly

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select count (*) 
from table 
where id in (1,2,3,4,5,6.....500)
```

These ID's are populated externally through some script. As soon as `In` parameter exceeds a certain number of entries, the query slows down 6 times.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated

Comment: Can't you just store those numbers into a temporary table, and then do a regular `INNER JOIN`? I would assume that would be much faster than an `IN` operation with a large number of values

Comment: Sounds like you need to read this homepage: http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: Internally, an `IN` clause is expanded into a bunch of `OR`s for the optimizer to choke on, so this inherently doesn't scale. Per marc, use a temp table or table variable. If you can't, another option is to join on a subquery that populates a table using a table value constructor. These are limited to 1000 rows to prevent exactly this sort of issue, but if that limit is not a problem they should still be faster than a huge `IN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been suggested in the comments, you can use a temporary table to populate the externally generated `ID`'s and then `join` on them. You can do create the temporary table as such :

```
Create table #TEMP(ID INT)
INSERT INTO #TEMP (ID) VALUES
(1), (2), (3), (4), (5) --Populate this with parameter as ID's are externally generated.
```

And then `join` as such :

```
Select          t.* 
from            table t
inner join      #Temp  temp on t.ID = temp.ID
```

I sincerely hope this is an example and you are not actually trying to do this :

```
Select count (*) 
from table 
where id in (1,2,3,4,5,6.....500)
```

Since if in your case, `ID`'s are unique (*which they mostly are*) and are not being deleted (*which is quite a usual practice*), then, the total number of `ID'`s in the `IN` clause will be the result of `COUNT(*)`, in which case, you don't have to have an `IN` clause. You can just count the total number of values in the parameter you plan to use in the `IN` clause and that should be good.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Hmm that last statement... the OP could have a table with an identity ID and there's no guarantee that there won't be gaps. So yeah, the `IN ...` would make some sense. However I would write `WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 500` if all numbers between 1 and 500 are in the list. I think the OP just gave an arbitrary example though, his RL case will likely be different.

Comment: @TT. Yes, that's absolutely correct . However, we don't know the specifics of the OP's case, we are merely speculating. As we have both mentioned, this is most likely an example and the OP actually has a more complex query on mind.